# Using loop variables

Tags: r

I would like to rename a large number of columns (column headers) to have numerical names rather than combined letter+number names. Because of the way the data is stored in raw format, I cannot just access the correct column numbers by using `data[[152]]` if I want to interact with a specific column of data (because random questions are filtered completely out of the data due to being long answer comments), but I'd like to be able to access them by `data$152`. Additionally, approximately half the columns names in my data have loaded with `class(data$152)` = NULL but `class(data[[152]])` = integer (and if I rename the `data[[152]]` file it appropriately allows me to see `class(data$152)` as integer).

Thus, is there a way to use the loop iteration number as a column name (something like below)

```
    for (n in 1:415) {
        names(data)[n] <-"n"    # name nth column after number 'n'
    }
```

That will reassign all my column headers and ensure that I do not run into question classes resulting in null?

As additional background info, my data is imported from a comma delimited .csv file with the value 99 assigned to answers of NA with the first row being the column names/headers

```
    data <- read.table("rawdata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings = "99")
```

There are 415 columns with headers in format Q001, Q002, etc
There are approximately 200 rows with no row labels/no label column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without a loop, as follows:

```
names(data) <- 1:415
```

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=2:5, c=3:6, d=4:7)
dat
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 4 5 6 7
```

Now rename the columns:

```
names(dat) <- 1:4
dat
  1 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 4 5 6 7
```

---

**EDIT : How to access your new data**

@Ramnath points out very accurately that you won't be able to access your data using `dat$1`:

```
dat$1
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "dat$1"
```

Instead, you will have to wrap the column names in backticks:

```
dat$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of character and numeric data to rename your columns.  This could be a much more convenient way of dealing with your problem:

```
names(dat) <- paste("x", 1:4, sep="")
dat
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: i think you must point out that accessing `dat$1` will throw an error. the OP needs to type the one within back ticks. moreover i think it is bad R practice to name columns using numbers

Comment: @Ramnat, very good point, thank you.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: ...and instead of `1:4`, `seq_len(ncol(dat))` would be more general - although `seq_along(dat)` also works since a data.frame is a list.

Comment: Thank you so much! That command is now my best friend! It solves all my NULL class problems and is way easier than trying to do a loop! I'd tried working with the paste function before and hadn't been able to get it to work, but I copied it exactly as you had and it works like a dream. Is there a good site that has good examples of how to do some things like this? Because I always search through many many websites looking for examples of commands to make data manipulation easier, and I finally ask here and get a simple answer that I somehow wasn't able to use elsewhere. Thanks again!